# How to make an entrance with custom fields for sign in to Google account

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I work at flutter.
I have a task when the user gets to the login page, he should see the login password field and enter their data (as in the picture), and not the button that offers google-button I found some examples but there is also no this, please tell me if there is such an option as it can be through the API to log in.

and in the future, I will need to work with the Google calendar.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date)
- https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed
- https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in
- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

[image]

Comment: Google auth is a secure method and protects the user's privacy, so they may not provide username & password login.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confuse if you don't want to offer the user to use google sign in don't use it then. You can use `Firebase Auth` instead to sign in with email and password like this:

```
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: txtEmail.text,
    password: txtPassword.text,
  );
```

It will check from `FirebaseAuthentication` on your `Firebase Project` whether the user already register with email and password in your database, so the user will be listed there with flag email instead of google, but if the user whom register with google reset their password which will apply to your apps only not their account they will get flag email and google.

[image]

So I suggest you make register page and then use the `FirebaseAuth` method:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: txtEmail.text, password: txtPassword.text)
```

Then the user will be listed in `Authentication` and they can login with email and password

Comment: So if I use this method I can use the login password from Google, and Google will check it through firebase?

Comment: Thank you very much, and then I could not understand why here at all firebase I needed to log in to Google, OK thank you again, I will try to figure it out!

Comment: Thanks it works for me https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed